# Не могу сделать клиент- серверное приложение

Tags: c#, sqlite, telegram, клиент-сервер, wcf

Делаю приложение, наподобие Telegram, но столкнулся с проблемой: не могу никак сделать сервер (в моём случае он должен быть локальный (консольное приложение, либо сервис)), который будет подключаться к базе данных  (в моём случае это SQLite), брать оттуда данные и передавать на сервер.

Например, клиент входит в систему и отправляет на сервер логин и пароль. После успешного прохождения данной операции он может просматривать друзей, отправлять сообщения и т.д. Пытался сделать на WCF, но не получилось.

Как это сделать? Если кто делал, подскажите, как это сделать, пожалуйста.

Comment: А что именно не получается? Запустить сервер или отправить запрос? В чём проблема?

Comment: не получается бд подключить и я не знаю что использовать, что бы всё чётко работало

Comment: Если вы не знаете, как подключить БД, то так и задайте вопрос: "Как подключить БД". Без упоминания лишнего: телеграма, клиент-сервера, wcf и пр. А сейчас ваш вопрос слишком общий.

Comment: Технология WCF уже считается устаревшей. Используйте SignalR (туториалов полно).

Comment: мне надо что бы сервер запускался сразу, а не при переходе в браузер или там можно сделать так?)

Comment: я знаю как подключить базу данных)))

Comment: Любой сервер запускается независимо от браузеров. Ваш вопрос стал еще более запутанным.

Comment: Давайте попробуем его распутать. Мне надо что бы сервер стартовал, при запуске клиента, то есть, клиент запустил программу, а вслед за клиентам запустился сервер, клиент вводит данные и они (данные) берутся с БД либо сохраняются в ней, надеюсь вы поняли

Comment: Сервер не будет стартовать при запуске клиента. Также как веб сервер не стартует при переходе на сайт в браузере. В момент когда клиент пытается подключиться к серверу, сервер уже должен быть запущен.

Comment: да, именно так, вот я клиента то сделал (было бы что делать там) а сервер не могу, надо что бы он был локальный и работал с базой данных

Comment: Проблема в автозапуске серверного приложения или что? За этим должна следить ОС, приложение нужно зарегистрировать как windows service/linux daemon

Comment: Хотите сделать сервер - сначала подумайте над тем как хотите к нему обращаться с клиента. Самое банальное - по http, то есть ваш сервер обычное asp приложение. Можете использовать стандартный шаблон проекта Worker Service, если хотите что-то своё.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RUZLIh4Vo20

Comment: как я хочу к нему обращаться?) хммммю...

Comment: ну я хочу просто что бы он запустился, как консолька, к примеру и всё

Comment: Ох... Если вам нужна консолька, то и создавайте консольное приложение. У вас должно быть два консольных проекта: сервер и клиент, соответственно.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Мне кажется, что у человека и есть 2 приложения, клиентское и серверное и он хочет, чтобы у него одновременно запускались оба проекта , просто он называет это "после запуска клиента, запускался сервер"

Comment: Правой кнопкой кликнуть по решение,в котором есть серверная часть и клиентска,далее в Общие свойства->Запускаемый проект  выбираете Несколько проектов.И будет у вас запускаться и клиентское приложение и серверное

Comment: Спасибо, понял
а как работать с БД
создаётся как, через код или я могу сделать её в SQLite и потом подключить к серверу

Comment: Не спрашивайте в комментариях! Их почти никто не видит. Если у вас появилось дополнение к _текущему_ вопросу, то отредактируйте его. Если у вас появился _новый_ вопрос, то задайте его отдельно, создав новую тему.